# Bulk load with perl DBI into Snowflake

Tags: perl, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a hash where I am storing 2 values to be inserted into a table in snowflake.  There are about 4.5 million rows to insert.  I have setup the following but the load is very slow.  I found out that it will allow me 16k records at a time.  Is there another method of bulk loading faster?

```
my $ccptable = "DWH_CCP.TGT.CCP_CNTC_BRDBAND_PING_DTL";
my ($sth, $sql);
$sql = "insert into $ccptable (op_hh_id,pstg_ts,load_ts) values (?, ?, current_timestamp)";
$sth = $dbh->prepare("$sql");

my (@col1, @col2);
my @status;
my $acctkeycnt = 0;
my $loopcnt = 0;
foreach my $acctkey (keys %allacctkeys) {
  my $timekey = $allacctkeys{$acctkey};
  $acctkeycnt++;
  push @col1, $acctkey;
  push @col2, $timekey;

  if ($acctkeycnt > 16000) {
    $loopcnt++;
    $sth->bind_param_array(1, \@col1);
    $sth->bind_param_array(2, \@col2);
    print "\nExecuting Array Load  Count => $loopcnt\n";
    $sth->execute_array( { ArrayTupleStatus => \@status } );
    @col1 = ();
    @col2 = ();
  }
}
```

Comment: Write the data out to a file in a stage and then use Snowflake’s COPY INTO command to bulk load it

Comment: I'm not sure how exactly this would work in PERL, but you might also want to investigate the Snowpipe Streaming API, since it appears that you are running individual inserts.  That won't be as good as a batch copy into, but should be faster than direct, single-record inserts.

Comment: thanks, gonna use the stage file and copy into.

Comment: DBI tends to have AutoCommit turned on by default, which can become a performance bottleneck for bulk inserts. You could try turning that off, or using explicit transactions. More info on [DBI docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#AutoCommit), or [Snowflake docs](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/transactions).